# Watch in directives controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i was trying to watch a scope variable inside a directives controller which i injected via template.But the listener never seems to trigger.

http://plnkr.co/edit/a9UWiVZlKhaKf0Z0utSG?p=preview

```
var angularSimpleAuth = angular.module('angularSimpleAuth', []);
angularSimpleAuth.directive('simpleAuthUsername',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope:{},
            template:'<input type="text" ng-model="userName" />',
            controller:function($scope){
                $scope.$watch('userName',function(val){
                    console.log('Value'+val);
                });
            },
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs,controllers) {
                console.log('In link for username');

            }
        };
    })
```

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here.Any help appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was you have the directive applied on input element.  Since the directive is rendering an input element already, it has either to be marked as a element or applied with a attribute replace true.

Change your HTML to:

```
    <simple-auth-username></simple-auth-username>
```

And the directive to:

```
angularSimpleAuth.directive('simpleAuthUsername',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{},
        template:'<input type="text" ng-model="userName" />',
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.$watch('userName',function(val){
                console.log('Value'+val);
            });
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs,controllers) {
            console.log('In link for username');

        }
    };
})
```

Comment: That worked!Also making replace true on my attribute directive also worked.Could you please tell me what is going on here.Thanks for the answer